# Retrieve list of users and groupsfrom ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using the in-built ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool in VS2005.

I have set up a few groups and a few users for my web application.

I would like to retrieve the list of users and groups from the application for my user management table in my web application.

May I know if there are any sample codes or step by step guides on the web ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes from `System.Web.Security` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

To get list of roles and users.

```
 System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection users=System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers();
 string[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
```